# jQuery -$ is not defined

Tags: jquery, laravel-blade

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" href="{{ url('js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <div id="main" class="row">

        @yield('content')

    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

I have above layout in blade template with following content

```
@extends('layout.layout')

@section('content')
<!-- some HTML -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    });
</script>

@endsection
```

I can verify by looking at source code in chrome, the jquery link is valid,

also tried moving script link to within the content,

but I am still getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

environment is vagrant with Laravel homestead image,

also calling jQuery function within console does show jQuery is loaded

Comment: From the "view page source" screen, click the link to the jQuery file and see what comes back. Is it jQuery?

Comment: yes it returns mini-fied jQuery content `/*! jQuery v3.3.1 | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/license */`

Comment: Well that's weird. Try replacing `$(document).ready(function(){...})` with `jQuery(function($){...})`

Comment: see other comment, I think it's due to IO slow on responding to mounted drive, I wonder how to fix it, I have included jQuery at work with no problem with vagrant setup

Comment: You aren't using the `defer` attribute on your `<script>` tag so it should block processing until the script loads. You can watch resources load in your browser's _Network_ console to confirm if it's a race condition or not

Comment: weird thing is in network it doesn't even show jQuery is been loaded, but I can still make jQuery function calls in console... replace the url with external jQuery, then network shows jQuery loaded

Comment: What jQuery calls would they be? Keep in mind, Chrome's console includes a `$` function as an alias for `document.querySelector()`. Try `$.fn.jquery` or `jQuery.fn.jquery` to really test for jQuery

Comment: i was doing `$('#id')`, but if I run `typeof jQuery.ajax` it shows jQuery undefined

Comment: Yeah, that'll be Chrome's alias. Could you show some screenshots from the "view page source" screen showing the `<script>` tag that includes jQuery? Are you sure it's in the page `<head>`? Can you also then show a screenshot after you click the `src` attribute?

Comment: Oh I found the problem is a silly mistake, I used `href` instead of `src` ... didn't realize that until you mention it, thank you so much, I wish I can give you credit

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="JavaScript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

try running it with that

Comment: that works, I guess it's IO slow at response on vagrant setup, is there anything I can do to fix that? when I tried setting `type: "nfs"` in homestead.yaml, the mounted folder ownership become root